# Getting choice from input

Tags: c, windows, input, multiple-choice

I want to prompt the user to press a key.This key will be stored in a variable and a `switch` statement is applied on the key to execute the corresponding command.I wrote a code,which seems a bit nasty and inefficient because it makes a call to the function `GetAsyncKeyState` in an exhausting way,specially if the keys are too many.Is there a simpler approach to this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int GetChoice(int *keys,size_t size);

int main(void)
{
    int keys[] = {'A','B','F'};
    int cKey = GetChoice(keys,3);
    switch(cKey)
    {
    case 'A':
        puts("you pressed : A!");
        break;
    case 'B':
        puts("you pressed : B!");
        break;
    case 'F':
        puts("you pressed : F!");
        break;
    }
    Sleep(2000);
    return 0;
}

int GetChoice(int *keys,size_t size)
{
    size_t n;
    while(1)
    {
        for(n = 0 ; n < size ; n++)
        {
            if(GetAsyncKeyState(keys[n]))
                return keys[n];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you need to only change from

```
int cKey = GetChoice(keys,3);
```

to

```
char cKey;
cKey=getch();
```

you do not need the

```
int GetChoice(int *keys,size_t size)
```

function. Just remove it too. Your entire code should look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main(void)
{

    char cKey;
    cKey=getch();
    switch(cKey)
    {
    case 'A':
        puts("you pressed : A!");
        break;
    case 'B':
        puts("you pressed : B!");
        break;
    case 'F':
        puts("you pressed : F!");
        break;
    }
    Sleep(2000);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing apples and oranges.  If you output messages with `puts()`, you should probably read input from standard input with `getchar()`.  Reading the keyboard state with `GetAsyncKeyState()` is only consistent if you display information on the screen using the Windows API.  Doing this in C has gone out of fashion a long time ago already.  Good luck!

Comment: `getchar` displays the entered key,and `puts` in my code is for the example.

Comment: @machine_1 then what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to program in C, use C constructs, not Windows constructs.  Take a look at K&R (Kernighan and Ritchie) section 1.5.  K&R is available in PDF form.  Just search for it.

If you use the async key state, you will have to apply your own detection for liftoff.